# Multiple Monitor setup is not remembered (Mint 17)

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, multi-monitor

After some issues with Ubuntu, I have decided to go to Mint.

Now new issues appear - I have three monitors, two horizonatally and one vertically. The problem is that after each reboot, Mint does not remember anything about the horizontal monitor and makes it back vertical.

Any idea how to tell Mint that I do not want to change my monitor setup every time after reboot?

I am using nVidia and I am making the setup via nVidia X server settings. Info for my video:

$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 041e (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fc8 (rev a1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved it. The way is the following:

> Find "Nvidia X ServerSettings"
>   fix the monitors manually 
>   Save to X Configuration file 
>   And it works!

Answer (score 0):

well as for a workaround you can compose  a xrandr command, add it to /etc/rc.local ...

Comment: A little more info on this?

Comment: Come on! Anyone?

Comment: Really? Noone???

Comment: Stop yelling and post output of
  '**xrandr -q**'

Comment: Or even better... https://www.google.lt/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&client=ubuntu#safe=off&q=xrandr%20three%20monitors

Comment: Here is the output: http://pastebin.com/ekFCu4rk Now what :) ?

Comment: And I am not yelling, I was just trying to attract attention. Excuse me, if you have considered it not appropriate.

Comment: It's been a while since I last used xrandr myself... try this:

    xrandr --auto --output DVI-D-0 --right-of VGA-0;
    xrandr --auto --output HDMI-0  --right-of DVI-D-0


run those two in terminal and see if anything changes. If it does but displays are in wrong positions - adjust commands accordingly.. they are pretty much self-explanatory I guess...

Comment: Hi Dude, I am not sure that you understand the issue - the problem is not that I cannot fix the monitors by myself, but that after each restart the vertical monitor (the VGA-0 connected one) is set back to horizontal.

Comment: Anyone willing to support me in my battle vs Mint?